# How do I get my user.address state and country fields included properly in my view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, select, menu, model, view

In my model, app/models/user.rb, I have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  …
  belongs_to :address
```

and in my model, I attempt to collect the address fields like so

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
…
    <%= f.fields_for :address do |addr| %>
    <%= addr.label :address, "Hometown" %><br/>
    <div class="field"><%= addr.text_field :city, placeholder: "City", :class => 'textField' %></div>
    <%= select_tag :state, options_for_select([["Select State", nil], *us_states]), {class: "selectField selectMenu form-control"} %>
    <%= country_code_select(:country, :country,
          [[ 'US', 'United States' ], [ 'CA', 'Canada' ]],
          {:include_blank=>true},
          {:style=>''}
          ) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

but when my state select menu is rendered, it is rendered with the id “state”, and submitting my user form doesn’t pick up my state (or country) menu.  What id do I need to include in my model to add the state and country into my user.address model?

Comment: can you show us what `*us_states` looks like? i think it needs to be `[[value, label],['ca', 'California']...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you should do like this

```
<%= f.fields_for :address do |addr| %>
    <%= addr.label :address, "Hometown" %><br/>
    <div class="field">
      <%= addr.text_field :city, placeholder: "City", :class => 'textField' %>
    </div>
    <%= addr.select :state,  *us_states, {prompt: 'Select State'}, class: "selectField selectMenu form-control" %>
    <%= addr.select :country,  [[ 'US', 'United States' ], [ 'CA', 'Canada' ]], { include_blank: true }%>
<% end %>
```

Hope this is helpful